# How do I configure a TextBox control to automatically resize itself vertically when text no longer fits on one line?

Tags: wpf, textbox, autosize

How do I configure a `TextBox` control to automatically resize itself vertically when text no longer fits on one line?

For example, in the following XAML:

```xml
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="0,0,0,0">
  <Border Name="dataGridHeader" 
    DataContext="{Binding Descriptor.Filter}"
    DockPanel.Dock="Top"                         
    BorderThickness="1"
    Style="{StaticResource ChamelionBorder}">
  <Border
    Padding="5"
    BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"                            
    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly=dc:NavigationPane, 
    ResourceId={x:Static dc:NavigationPaneColors.NavPaneTitleBorder}}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock                                
        Name="DataGridTitle"                                                                                                
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="Bold"                                    
        Foreground="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey 
        TypeInTargetAssembly=dc:NavigationPane, 
        ResourceId={x:Static dc:NavigationPaneColors.NavPaneTitleForeground}}}"/>
      <StackPanel Margin="5,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" 
              Visibility="{Binding IsFilterEnabled, FallbackValue=Collapsed, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding IsFilterEnabled, FallbackValue=false}"  >                                    
          <TextBlock  />                                                                
          <TextBox    
            Name="VerticallyExpandMe"
            Padding="0, 0, 0, 0"  
            Margin="10,2,10,-1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"                                    
            Text="{Binding QueryString}"
            Foreground="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey 
            TypeInTargetAssembly=dc:NavigationPane, 
            ResourceId={x:Static dc:NavigationPaneColors.NavPaneTitleForeground}}}">
          </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>                               
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>              
  </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

The `TextBox` control named "VerticallyExpandMe" needs to automatically expand vertically when the text bound to it does not fit on one line.  With `AcceptsReturn` set to true, `TextBox` expands vertically if I press enter within it, but I want it do do this automatically.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Although Andre Luus's suggestion is basically correct, it won't actually work here, because your layout will defeat text wrapping. I'll explain why.

Fundamentally, the problem is this: text wrapping only does anything when an element's width is constrained, but your `TextBox` has unconstrained width because it's a descendant of a horizontal `StackPanel`. (Well, two horizontal stack panels. Possibly more, depending on the context from which you took your example.) Since the width is unconstrained, the `TextBox` has no idea when it is supposed to start wrapping, and so it will never wrap, even if you enable wrapping. You need to do two things: constrain its width and enable wrapping.

Here's a more detailed explanation.

Your example contains a lot of detail irrelevant to the problem. Here's a version I've trimmed down somewhat to make it easier to explain what's wrong:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Name="DataGridTitle" />
    <StackPanel
        Margin="5,0"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        >
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBox
            Name="VerticallyExpandMe"
            Margin="10,2,10,-1"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding QueryString}"
            >
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

So I've removed your containing `DockPanel` and the two nested `Border` elements inside of that, because they're neither part of the problem nor relevant to the solution. So I'm starting at the pair of nested `StackPanel` elements in your example. And I've also removed most of the attributes because most of them are also not relevant to the layout.

This looks a bit weird - having two nested horizontal stack panels like this looks redundant, but it does actually make sense in your original if you need to make the nested one visible or invisible at runtime. But it makes it easier to see the problem.

(The empty `TextBlock` tag is also weird, but that's exactly as it appears in your original. That doesn't appear to be doing anything useful.)

And here's the problem: your `TextBox` is inside some horizontal `StackPanel` elements, meaning its width is unconstrained - you have inadvertently told the text box that it is free to grow to any width, regardless of how much space is actually available.

A `StackPanel` will always perform layout that is unconstrained in the direction of stacking. So when it comes to lay out that `TextBox`, it'll pass in a horizontal size of `double.PositiveInfinity` to the `TextBox`. So the `TextBox` will always think it has more space than it needs. Moreover, when a child of a `StackPanel` asks for more space than is actually available, the `StackPanel` lies, and pretends to give it that much space, but then crops it.

(This is the price you pay for the extreme simplicity of `StackPanel` - it's simple to the point of being bone-headed, because it will happily construct layouts that don't actually fit. You should only use `StackPanel` if either you really do have unlimited space because you're inside a `ScrollViewer`, or you are certain that you have sufficiently few items that you're not going to run out of space, or if you don't care about items running off the end of the panel when they get too large and you don't want the layout system to try to do anything more clever than simply cropping the content.)

So turning on text wrapping won't help here, because the `StackPanel` will always pretend that there's more than enough space for the text.

You need a different layout structure. Stack panels are the wrong thing to use because they will not impose the layout constraint you need to get text wrapping to kick in.

Here's a simple example that does roughly what you want:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="DataGridTitle"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            />
        <TextBox
            Name="VerticallyExpandMe"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="{Binding QueryString}"
            >
        </TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

If you create a brand new WPF application and paste that in as the content of the main window, you should find it does what you want - the `TextBox` starts out one line tall, fills the available width, and if you type text in, it'll grow one line at a time as you add more text.

Of course, layout behaviour is always sensitive to context, so it may not be enough to just throw that into the middle of your existing application. That will work if pasted into a fixed-size space (e.g. as the body of a window), but will not work correctly if you paste it into a context where width is unconstrained. (E.g., inside a `ScrollViewer`, or inside a horizontal `StackPanel`.)

So if this doesn't work for you, it'll be because of other things wrong elsewhere in your layout - possibly yet more `StackPanel` elements elsewhere. From the look of your example, it's probably worth spending some time thinking about what you really need in your layout and simplifying it - the presence of negative margins, and elements that don't appear to do anything like that empty `TextBlock` are usually indicative of an over-complicated layout. And unnecessary complexity in a layout makes it much hard to achieve the effects you're looking for.

Comment: Do not know how to express my thanks but this is a truely great response.  You made me understand the problem and provided a very good solution putting it in very simple terms.  Yes, I should have cleaned things up a bit before posting as it distracts away from the problem.  Will learn for next time.  Thanks again.

Comment: Nice answer Ian. Didn't have the time to confirm but wanted to suggest setting MaxWidth on the TextBlock. +1

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, you could constrain your `TextBlock`'s `Width` by binding it to a parent's `ActualWidth`, for example:

```
<TextBlock Width="{Binding ElementName=*ParentElement*, Path=ActualWidth}" 
           Height="Auto" />
```

This will force it to resize its height automatically too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MaxWidth` and `TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using another simple approach that allows me not to change the document layout.

The main idea is not to set the control `Width` before it starts changing. For `TextBox`es, I handle the `SizeChanged` event:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" SizeChanged="TextBox_SizeChanged" />

private void TextBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement box = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    if (e.PreviousSize.Width == 0 || box.Width < e.PreviousSize.Width)
        return;
    box.Width = e.PreviousSize.Width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class which extends TextBlock. It does auto-shrinking and takes MaxHeight / MaxWidth into consideration:

```
public class TextBlockAutoShrink : TextBlock
    {
        private double _defaultMargin = 6;
        private Typeface _typeface;

        static TextBlockAutoShrink()
        {
            TextBlock.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBlockAutoShrink), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TextPropertyChanged)));
        }

        public TextBlockAutoShrink() : base() 
        {
            _typeface = new Typeface(this.FontFamily, this.FontStyle, this.FontWeight, this.FontStretch, this.FontFamily);
            base.DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(TextBlockAutoShrink_DataContextChanged);
        }

        private static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var t = sender as TextBlockAutoShrink;
            if (t != null)
            {
                t.FitSize();
            }
        }

        void TextBlockAutoShrink_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FitSize();
        }

        protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
        {
            FitSize();

            base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        }


        private void FitSize()
        {
            FrameworkElement parent = this.Parent as FrameworkElement;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                var targetWidthSize = this.FontSize;
                var targetHeightSize = this.FontSize;

                var maxWidth = double.IsInfinity(this.MaxWidth) ? parent.ActualWidth : this.MaxWidth;
                var maxHeight = double.IsInfinity(this.MaxHeight) ? parent.ActualHeight : this.MaxHeight;

                if (this.ActualWidth > maxWidth)
                {
                    targetWidthSize = (double)(this.FontSize * (maxWidth / (this.ActualWidth + _defaultMargin)));
                }

                if (this.ActualHeight > maxHeight)
                {
                    var ratio = maxHeight / (this.ActualHeight);

                    // Normalize due to Height miscalculation. We do it step by step repeatedly until the requested height is reached. Once the fontsize is changed, this event is re-raised
                    // And the ActualHeight is lowered a bit more until it doesnt enter the enclosing If block.
                    ratio = (1 - ratio > 0.04) ? Math.Sqrt(ratio) : ratio;

                    targetHeightSize = (double)(this.FontSize *  ratio);
                }

                this.FontSize = Math.Min(targetWidthSize, targetHeightSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be more in the meaning of WPF if the functionality is encapsulated within a behavior. You should not subclass controls.

Comment: It is true but in my case it was so commonly used throughout our system that I just wanted to make sure the same behaviour is used across all instances and it was a better way to maintain it. In general I think its good to keep in mind that in Software just like in Life itself, there is no One rule to fit them all.