# WPF - Multiline TextBox text gets blurry while typing a long text

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, blurry

I have a textBox that grows vertically while typing. Unfortunately when I type a long text (for example a 3 line text) some PART of it gets blurry. What's more, when I prevent it from growing vertically and make it grow horizontally it works fine - the text is sharp then.

What I've tried:

```
UseLayoutRounding = true;
RenderOptions.TextRenderingMode = "ClearType";
```

Please forget about

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode = "Display"
```

It has to be "Ideal".

See the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answers: [WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions)

Comment: Nothing seems to work there for me.

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the issue. Is this specific to a certain version of Windows, .net version, software or hardware rendering, video card, etc?

Comment: If you want to keep Ideal, there's may not be a solution. You can try all combination for (TextRenderingMode, TextFormattingMode, ClearTypeHint, SnapToDevicePixels), and the size of the text also matters. This "root" article pretty says it all: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Disable SubPixel Rendering and Anti-Aliasing. Try

```
SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned:

> I have a textBox that grows vertically while typing

I assume then that it's a `CustomControl` derived from `TextBox` and with a **custom rendering** to grow vertically instead of using the builtin text **wrap ability**.

Since I was unable to reproduce your issue with the stock TextBox and the parameters (with **`Ideal`**) you mentioned (*I've checked from Framework 4.0 to 4.6 on VS 2013*), maybe the **blur comes from your custom code**.

**By the way, with not using the builtin wrap?**

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
```

Maybe you should include more code and details, like framework version, visual studio version, OS version and so on.

Likewise, specify your version of "Textbox that grows vertically". Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275249/how-do-i-configure-a-textbox-control-to-automatically-resize-itself-vertically-w) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the font size of the textbox just a tiny amount (use 1/4s if in pixels). Alternatively, try changing the line height slightly in a similar fashion. I think the problem might be down to WPF's interpretation of the sub-pixels and may be rounding off at the wrong place.